# getTextFormat().size returning different values from the timeline as from a class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm working on an AS3 project in Flash CS5. I have a dynamic textfield called `aiMoneyText`, and when I try to get its font size like so:

```
root["aiMoneyText"].getTextFormat().size
```

I get `null`. That code is in a class that gets called from the Actions pane in the frame that the textfield is on. I pass `root` to that class in the constructor. The weird thing is, if I put that line of code *directly* in the Actions pane, rather than in a class, it returns the correct value.

What's going on? How can the location of this line of code affect its output?

Link to .fla: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/93726541/Poker/main.fla

Classes:

- [Main](http://pastebin.com/kwkRZFqk) (Document Class)
- [Game](http://pastebin.com/hg6gphgC)

Comment: I realize now this is probably because the code is being called before the TextField is being added to the stage. Is there a way around that?

Comment: root from the timeline returns MainTimeline. I think you'd want to verify first that the root you are passing to the constructor is not null. Second, if it is not null, verify that is the correct root ( MainTimeline is what you are looking for it sounds like? But root will be different depending on where you are using it from ). Lastly, if that doesn't work you probably need to use MovieClip(root).aiMoneyText. If you want to use the root after it's been added to the stage, in the constructor make an ADDED_TO_STAGE event that will run once it's been added, then you can access the root.

Comment: I can probably put all this down in an answer, but I figured I'd hear from you first on where the textfield is located ( timeline or from another class that hasn't been added to the display list by chance )

Comment: @BennetYeates Which object do I add the event listener to? I tried adding it to the textfield but it doesn't seem to have worked (the event never fires).

Comment: ADDED_TO_STAGE is only useful for DisplayObjects. So if you have a class that is extending DisplayObject( Sprite, MovieClip, etc ) that contains your TextField, you add to that class, not the TextField object.

Comment: @BennettYeates So I would add it to `root`?

Comment: Also, the TextField is on the main timeline in the first frame. I put it there in Flash itself, as in in the .fla, not through code.

Comment: Hmm I see, can you upload your .fla? Might be a few things going on there, the first thing that pops into my mind is that your TextField may be null on the frame you attempt the getTextFormat()

Comment: @BennettYeates I've edited a link into my post.

Comment: That link is not correct.

Comment: Can you post your class files as well.

Comment: @BennettYeates Sure, sorry.

Comment: Go to this link: http://collabedit.com/np4fm

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest creating a document class for your fla. Create a movie clip class and add the class name to the "Class" field in the property panel with Document "selected". Document appears when nothing is selected in the fla.

The document class will then act as your timeline script because it automatically is added to the display list and you can do things like add the ADDED_TO_STAGE event listener to the document class constructor. This will also allow you to reference the textField directly from the document class rather than using "root" which is a bad idea.

Your text field should then be available in the ADDED_TO_STAGE handler and all subsequent frames from the document class.

Comment: Thanks, I'd forgotten all about Document Classes. But, even after making this change, I'm still getting null from the text format, even inside the myDocumentClass.onAddedToStage handler.

Comment: Have you checked if you can access "aiMoneyText" in other ways like setting its .text? Or check if its on the display list? You aren't using root are you?

Answer (score 0):

As discussed the resolution required an explicit setting of the `TextFormat` on a field containing text. As no text was set for the text property, run time did not create an available `TextFormat` Object with the set property `size`.

Some notable pieces after reviewing the code:

- Remember when instantiating a new object you need to hold a reference to it if you plan on using it, otherwise it will be created, lose scope, and be ready for garbage collection.

  (i.e. - `new Game(this)`, needed a reference... - `var myGame:Game = new Game(this);` )
- Be cautious creating a class level variable named `root` when extending that class from `DisplayObject`.`DisplayObject` have an inherited reference called `root` already.

Good luck!